# MySql Inner Join with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, mysql-error-1064

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT table1.f_id  FROM table1 WHERE table1.f_com_id = '430' AND      
 table1.f_status = 'Submitted' 
 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table2.f_id = table1.f_id
 where table2.f_type = 'InProcess'
```

I need information from `table1` as all the id associated with `f_com_id` as 430 and status as submitted and the type should be only in process which is stored in other table(`table2`)

`f_id` is `p_key` and `f_key` in both the tables.
But this giving me errors, I think I am placing the `WHERE` clause wrong, how to fix it.?

> Error msg: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN table2
>   ON table2.f_id = ' at line 2

Comment: Almost 80k views, ~12 votes on question and answer with 25+ votes. Surely not too localized.

Comment: A very popular syntax error, yes. Possibly not too localized, but off-topic nonetheless, like the other syntax errors.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes you are right. You have placed `WHERE` clause wrong. You can only use one `WHERE` clause in single query so try `AND` for multiple conditions like this:

```
 SELECT table1.f_id  FROM table1 
   INNER JOIN table2
     ON table2.f_id = table1.f_id
 WHERE table2.f_type = 'InProcess'
   AND f_com_id = '430'
   AND f_status = 'Submitted'
```

Comment: thnx a lot..it worked for me.. but what i feel is JOIN operations are always a costier approach,  can we do this some other way whithout using join opertaion. if possible?

Comment: @AdityaKumar Join is better approach than others (e.g. sub-query etc.). Prefer join . See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3db23/3).

Answer (score 14):

1. Change the INNER JOIN before the WHERE clause.
2. You have two WHEREs which is not allowed.

Try this:

> ```
> SELECT table1.f_id FROM table1
>   INNER JOIN table2 
>      ON (table2.f_id = table1.f_id AND table2.f_type = 'InProcess') 
>    WHERE table1.f_com_id = '430' AND table1.f_status = 'Submitted'
> ```

Comment: strangely, the parentheses resolved my issue

Answer (score 2):

You could only write one where clause.

```
 SELECT table1.f_id  FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table2.f_id = table1.f_id
 where table1.f_com_id = '430' AND      
 table1.f_status = 'Submitted' AND table2.f_type = 'InProcess'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two `WHERE` clauses but only one is allowed. Use it like this:

```
SELECT table1.f_id FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.f_id = table1.f_id
WHERE
  table1.f_com_id = '430'
  AND table1.f_status = 'Submitted'
  AND table2.f_type = 'InProcess'
```