# how to fetch values from another table which are not in first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get values of `c.cf_condition`, `c.cf_condition_value` and `c.cf_warranty` from table 2. These attributes are not in table 1. I used every join condition but nothing happened. These values can be show with inner join but without `WHERE p.cf_IsDailyDeal=1` condition. If i am not right this where clause then my required rows not shown. I want to fetch three attributes but with this where clause:

```
SELECT p.im_folder,
p.im_name,
p.cf_price_check,
p.category_id,
p.classifieds_id,
p.cf_price_check,
p.classifieds_id,
p.cf_title,
p.cf_addeddate,
p.cf_price,
(SELECT c.cf_condition FROM as_classifieds as c WHERE c.classifieds_id = p.classifieds_id),
(SELECT c.cf_condition_value FROM as_classifieds as c WHERE c.classifieds_id = p.classifieds_id),
(SELECT c.cf_warranty FROM as_classifieds as c WHERE c.classifieds_id = p.classifieds_id)
FROM as_index_classifieds as p 
WHERE p.cf_IsDailyDeal=1;
```

Comment: You can look
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364602/mysql-inner-join-with-where-clause) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153665/inner-join-where-clause) for answers

Comment: I can not understand your question. An attempt at clarification might be useful, perhaps with some sample data.

Comment: i want to get values of columns c.cf_condition, c.cf_condition_value and c.cf_warranty from table 'as_classifieds' . these columns are not in table 'as_index_classifieds' , i use select query on 2nd table , i want these 3 values show when i echo those

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, ¿this is not working for you?

```
SELECT 
p.im_folder,
p.im_name,
p.cf_price_check, 
p.category_id,
p.classifieds_id,
p.cf_price_check, 
p.classifieds_id,
p.cf_title, 
p.cf_addeddate, 
p.cf_price,
c.cf_condition, 
c.cf_condition_value, 
c.cf_warranty 
FROM as_index_classifieds as p 
LEFT JOIN as_classifieds as c 
ON p.classifieds_id = c.classifieds_id  
WHERE p.cf_IsDailyDeal=1;
```

This should give you those 3 attributes for the rows from table 1 with same id as table 2 where dailyDeal is 1

Comment: no i have tried  this but  c.cf_condition, 
c.cf_condition_value, 
c.cf_warranty not showing their values,,,  i want these columns values ..

Comment: Can you give some examples of your tables contents, of the 2 rows you want to mix. As Anders said, some sample data might help